# Getting: Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Tags: php, scope, static-methods

I'm using php 5.3.13. This script is for login remember me system but when I login with "remember me" it's giving me this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\oops_login_system\ooplr\classes\User.php

The code is as follows:

login.php

```
$user = new User();
$remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? TRUE : FALSE;
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
```

user.php

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = FALSE) {

    if (!$username && !$password && !$this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        if ($user) {
            if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                if ($remember) {
                    $hash = Hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('user_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
                    if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else {
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }

                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a var_dump of $hashCheck - maybe it is null instead of a collection

Comment: its returning bool false.

Comment: So that is your problem, have you checked whether there is a user session with the provided ID in the database?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
 $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('user_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
```

you are getting something which not an object, so you can't call `$hashCheck->count()` in the next line. You should what exactly do you get and why (is this a bug or planned behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Hi check the following in your code.
$hashCheck = $this->_db->get('user_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

It should be $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', xxxxxxxxx

The count looks in users_session table but u are trying to get a table that does not exist.

Well thats how i understand it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
count($hashCheck)
```

indesd of

```
$hashCheck->count()
```

if does not worked, so $hashCheck is null, then chage the line

```
if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
```

to

```
if ($hashCheck && $hashCheck->count() > 0){
```

Comment: now its giving again a Fatal error: Call to a member function first() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\oops_login_system\ooplr\classes\User.php
kindly give any other idea..

Comment: $hashCheck is null for sure.
so check to see user_session and user_id name are find in DB?